# Cannot convert array of doubles to array

Tags: java, arrays, double

I am currently doing an assignment for my high school computer science class and I am running into an issue where I get the error "double[] cannot be converted to double". However, I'm very confused because I'm telling one specific method to return a double array.

```
public static double [] getHits(int attempts) {
    Random ranInt = new Random();
    int range = ranInt.nextInt(2) - 1;

    double hits = 0;
    double [] hitsInTrial = new double[attempts];
    double radius = 1;
    double x = Math.pow( range, 2);
    double y = Math.pow( range, 2);

    for( int index = 0; index < attempts; index++)
    {
        if( !(x + y <= radius) )
        {
            hits++;
        }

        hitsInTrial[index] = hits;
    }

    return hitsInTrial;
}
```

^This method is supposed to return the double array of hitsInTrial (I feel as if some data is wrong but I'll worry about that after I get my issue resolved).

```
public static void main()
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many darts/trials?: ");
    int dartThrows = in.nextInt();

    double[] trials = new double[10];
    double[] hits = new double[dartThrows];

    for( int index = 0; index < trials.length; index++)
    {
        hits[index] = getHits( dartThrows );
    }
}
```

I am getting the error in the hit[index] = getsHits( dartThrows ); area. I'm very confused because the method getHits is told to return an array of doubles, but I'm getting the "Cannot be converted" error. Any help would be greatly appreciated because as a newbie, I'm not quite sure what's wrong.

I have left out two methods, one to calculate pi using the data, and one to print the results. No errors are generated in those methods but if I need to provide them to help with an answer please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

Your `getHits()` method returns an array of doubles: `double[]`. Whereas your `hits[]` array is of type `double[]`, so its element is of type `double`. You try to assign a `double[]` return value to it.

Answer (score 1):

Do `hits = getHits( dartThrows );`

You are trying to assign the array of doubles to a double element in the array.

```
hits[a] // Represents a double element at index a not the array itself
```